# swagger codegen config file for sample code

Tags: config, swagger-codegen

My python and perl samples have disappeared from the documentation [old docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nihk.png) after I updated my local swagger [docs now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhxyr.png).
I know there must be a config file somewhere that will define which samples to display. Where do I find this? How do I define which libraries to display in my Usages and Samples?

I'm using Swagger 2.

I have found this in the README: 
To control the specific files being generated, you can pass a CSV list of what you want: ```sh

The SDK has not changed and still generates the correct libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by re-cloning the swagger-codegen repo and running the mvn command. I have also found that in the src/main/resources I can change the htmlDocs2 files and see the results after running the mvn command. Would love to know more about this. Not seeing many swagger questions getting answered.